# Sinch FCM based push notification

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

While implementing app-app calling with Sinch, I need to integrate push notification using firebase cloud messaging(FCM). As there is no doc available so I followed the same process like GCM but when I called

**mSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);**

it is throwing exception missing GCM exception

**com.sinch.android.rtc.MissingGCMException: Can't enable managed push as this depends on GCM, which is not available on this device**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Besides adding firebase to the dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

I had to add play-services as well:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

After that the exception was not raised anymore and I could receive notifications.

Answer (score 1):

We currently do not support FCM for managedpush if you cant use GCM use this to implement the push methods your self https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#pushnotificationssentviayourapplicationserver

Comment: Any update for this change over latest SDK 'sinch-android-rtc-3.11.1' ? Because still getting the issue even If I have updated it to the latest version of SINCH SDK

Comment: @Jigar the latest version of the Sinch Android sdk contains an example with ManagedPush that works with FCM "sinch-rtc-sample-push". Maybe that helps?

Comment: @TamaraBernad - Thanks. I just saw that and it seems like it will solve all of my trouble. Will let you know once I'll implement it in my actual project.